# PrestaSitemapBundle dump error when trying to create Sitemap

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

I'm using [prestashop](https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle/blob/3.x/doc/4-dynamic-routes-usage.md) documentation to create sitemap.

When I run following command

```
php bin/console presta:sitemaps:dump
```

I get following error:

```
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "post".
```

Following is the code for post in Controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/{id}/{slug}", name="post")
 */
public function show_post(ManagerRegistry $manager, $id)
{
    $post =  $manager->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);

    return $this->render('main/show_post.html.twig',[
        'post' => $post
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add a `$slug` as well to `show_post` function parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, adding id in SitemapSubscriber did a fine job.